# Setting text width in html in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla

I'm trying to limit text width while centering in html and having no luck - it keeps flushing left. How can I limit text and center?

I've tried setting the text width via pixels.

```html
<header>
<h2 style="text-align: center;">
    <strong>
        <img src="images/unnamed-3.jpg" alt="unnamed 3" width="472" height="331" />
        <br />
        <br />Join in The SA+C’s Summer Giving Challenge&nbsp;
    </strong>
</h2>
<p style="width: 800px; text-align: center;">It’s an exciting time for the SA+C. The Seaport area is developing fast and we must keep up our efforts to remain visible. We advocate for our artists by offering creative craft experiences and meaningful engagements beyond the “normal and expected.”
    <br />
    <br />
    <a class="uk-button" style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 1rem;" href="index.php?option=com_config&amp;controller=config.display.modules&amp;id=370&amp;Itemid=189&amp;return=aHR0cHM6Ly9zb2NpZXR5b2ZjcmFmdHMub3JnLw%3D%3D">Join the campaign today!
    </a>
</p>
</header>
```

Text is flushing left instead of centering.

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `width: 800px;` you can use margin like this:

```
<p style="margin: 0 200px; text-align: center;">
```

or this:

```
<p style="margin: 0 20%; text-align: center;">
```

where the first number sets top and bottom margins and the second number sets the left and right margins.